# How to drag and drop table row in ASP.Net MVC3 using jquery without using any plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using datatable plugin in my ASP.Net MVC3 project. Here I have to implement the
row reordering. I used "jQuery.dataTables.rowReordering.js" plugin to implement it. For ui its
working fine, but It failed to call server side function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myDataTable').dataTable().rowReordering({sURL: "/AdminArea/UpdateOrder" });
    });
</script>
```

my controller code is

```
public ActionResult Index()
 {
   return View(db.AdminAreas.ToList());
 }

public void UpdateOrder(int id, int fromPosition, int toPosition, string direction)
{
}
```

View

```
<table id="myDataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            OrderNo
        </th>        
        <th>
            SubArea
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>        

    </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
@{
    if (@ViewData["SubAreaForArea"] != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<GridDragAndDrop.Models.SubAreaForAdmin> subarea = ViewData["SubAreaForArea"] as IEnumerable<GridDragAndDrop.Models.SubAreaForAdmin>;

        foreach (var item in subarea)
        {
            <tr class="order">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.OrderNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubArea)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I could not find the problem. So Please Help me to implement row drag and drop using 
jquery. Also the updated order will be updated in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change **Updateorder** function to

```
public void UpdateOrder(int id, string fromPosition, string toPosition, string direction)
```

because jQuery data table implements AJAX functionality with mime type `("text")`